# How to view fullcalendar events in laravel 2020?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, controller, fullcalendar

iam making a fullcalendar integration in laravel 2020 version , i had successfully made update , delete,create but after refreshing the page the event is not shown in the calendar besides it gets stored in the database. here is my code

view

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: true,
                events: SITEURL + "/fullcalendareventmaster",
                displayEventTime: true,
                editable: true,
                eventRender: function (event, element, view) 
                {
                    if (event.allDay === 'true') 
                    {
                        event.allDay = true;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        event.allDay = false;
                    }
                },
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
```

controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            $start = (!empty($_GET["start"])) ? ($_GET["start"]) : ('');
            $end = (!empty($_GET["end"])) ? ($_GET["end"]) : ('');
            $data = Event::whereDate('start','>=', $start)->whereDate('end','<=', $end)->get(['id','title','start','end']);
            return Response::json($data);
        }
        return view('fullcalender');
    }
```

Comment: have you checked the contents of the JSON being returned by Laravel, to see if the event is there? If so, does the event have valid data? Are there any console errors in the browser? You need to do some debugging before we can help you - the code alone doesn't explain the issue.

Comment: yeah the json was displayed and it has no errors

Comment: Hm, if it had no errors or problems then it would work in fullcalendar, and you wouldn't be asking us a question. Please show us the JSON being generated by your code (as output in the Response tab of you browser's network tool when fullCalendar tries to make the request to download the events). or maybe the new event is simply not there? Maybe it didn't get returned by the database query? Have you debugged that possibility?